# Почему в C++ `auto` не работает для массива внутри функции?

Tags: c++

Перехожу с С на С++. Не могу понять почему `auto` не работает для массива внутри функции. С вектором все в порядке, если попробовать в `main` - все в порядке, а вот именно внутри функции не работает. Из-за чего?

```
void foo(int a[10])
{
    for (int x : a)
        std::cout << x << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ (и С кстати тоже) не разрешает передачу массива по значению. Вместо этого тип аргумента изменяется. В этом контексте `a` не является массивом, а имеет тип `int *`. Если хотите работать с массивом - передавайте по ссылке или по указателю:

```
void foo(int ( & a )[10])
{
    for (int x : a)
        std::cout << x << " ";
}
```

А еще лучше - использовать `::std::array` или `array_view`.

Comment: То есть тут ```a``` просто указатель на нулевой элемент?

Comment: Именно так. В этом можно убедится написав `static_assert(::std::is_same_v<int *, decltype(a)>);`

Comment: А есть ли вообще смысл использования массивов вместо векторов в с++?

Comment: Ну сишных массивов использовать нет особого смысла, разве что для взаимодействия с кодом на С. А ::std::array или array_view - очень даже есть.